# FETCH Backbone data collection with manual params

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to fetch Backbone Collection by manual url, setted as param to collection's fetch method. But, when it try to fetch, return an error

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

This is load method, receiving params, where executes fetch method:

```
    load: function(options) {
        this.collection.fetch({url : '/UserProducts/Subscription/' + options.id});
    },
```

Is this possible to set custom params to url like this, without set it in collection constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the annotated source, the `urlError` is invoked only if you haven't passed a url in the options, and no url is specified in the model/collection constructor as well:

```
if (!options.url) {
  params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
}
```

Otherwise backbone shouldn't be throwing this error.

Your code should be working fine, you should try upgrading to the latest version of backbone.

Comment: Thanks, seems like old version of Backbone cause the problem!